# JSP request.getParameter

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following page in JSP:

```
    <%String a= request.getParameter("Test"); 
    System.out.println(a);%>

    <form > 
    <input type="text" name="Test" value= "Whatever" >
    </form>
```

If I start, it shows me on the consule "null" why?
Sorry for this very basic question!

Comment: And did you submit the form?

Comment: Yes the form ist shown with "whatever"

Comment: That's great! But did you submit the form? Is there a request parameter in your current url? Because there should be if you've submitted the form. Your form has no submit button, but I'm guessing there isn't. Add `?Test=something` and hit enter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do as follow code:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   <%String a= request.getParameter("Test"); 
    System.out.println(a);%>
    <form action="#"> 
    <input type="text" name="Test" value= "Whatever" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click submit the console will print Whatever。But when you first visit the page, the console is printed as null

Answer (score 2):

You need to have this code distributed in two different JSPs:

First JSP:

```
<form > 
  <input type="text" name="Test" value= "Whatever" >
</form>
```

Then you need to submit this form from your browser. In your servlet doPost handler, you need to dispatch the second JSP which will have the following code:

```
 <%String a= request.getParameter("Test"); 
    System.out.println(a);%>
```

**Update**:

As one of the fellow reviewers notate, you can always use the same JSP before and after the form submission. In this case, the first one will still print null while the second one will print the desired output. The key is that the form must be submitted in order for the form parameters to be populated to the request context automatically.

Comment: He could quite easily forward back to the same JSP after submission.

Comment: @AlanHay. Absolutely. But the first JSP compilation would still print null. Once he submits the first one and the second time compilation would see the request param "test". The key is that the form must be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

> If I start, it shows me on the consule "null" why?

Everyone else has answered, how to do the right thing. Let me tell, why it is doing what it is doing. Since, there is nothing in the request and everything is just plain GET request, so `request.getParameter("Test");` resolves nothing and returns `null` in response.

You can probably try to invoke this page as:

`http://whatever.com:PORT_IF_ANY/CONTEXT?Test=Whatever`

You will then see your page printing `Whatever` instead of null. So, long story short, since your request doesn't has the parameter named as `Test`,  it evaluates to `null` and you print that `null`.